# Proving a matrix property of unnormalized laplacian matrix of a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the symmetric real $n\times n$ matrix $W$. Define $d_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_{ij}$. Define $D$ as the diagonal matrix with $d_i$ as its diagonal entries. Define $L=D-W$ as the laplacian matrix. Now I need to prove the following property that for any vector $f\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $$f^TLf=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}w_{ij}(f_i-f_j)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks very straightforward:
\begin{align}
2f^T(D-W)f
&= 2\sum_i d_if_i^2 - 2\sum_{i,j}w_{ij}f_if_j\\
&= \sum_i d_if_i^2 + \sum_j d_jf_j^2 - 2\sum_{i,j}w_{ij}f_if_j\\
&= \sum_{i,j} w_{ij}f_i^2 + \sum_{j,i} w_{ji}f_j^2 - 2\sum_{i,j}w_{ij}f_if_j\\
&= \sum_{i,j} w_{ij}(f_i-f_j)^2\quad(\text{because } w_{ji}=w_{ij}).
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, I knew this answer. I was looking for an answer which is more matrix-vector style. For instance, for a given vector $f$, I define the matrix $F_s=[f_{ij}]$ where $f_{ij}=(f_i-f_j)^2$. Now, can I prove $2f^T(D-W)f = e^T(W\odot F_s)e$ using only vectors and matrices without using their individual elements. Here $e$ is the all ones vector. $\odot$ is the hadamard product.

Comment: you are allowed to use kronecker products, columns of identity matrices and all those similar matrix-vector operations